# Переключение между окнами при условии. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Нужно: при заполнении полей 'login' и 'password' строками "admin", мы переходили на некст окно, если же символы другие - ошибка.
[image: то как выглядит окно]

Сам код:

```
  public void handlSingIn() throws Exception {
        
        if( ) {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("variety.fxml"));
            Stage window = (Stage) SingInButton.getScene().getWindow();
            window.setScene(new Scene(root));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень много готовых решений уже сделано. Попробуйте повторить то, что сделано на этом сайте:[betacode].

https://betacode.net/11533/open-a-new-window-in-javafx

Например при верном вводе у вас открывается окно со следующей информации,а при неправильном другое окно с другой информацией